# React-Native Android Error: Cannot run Project.afterEvaluate(Closure)

Tags: android, react-native

Getting the following error when trying to build my react native android app on Android Studio despite not making any changes on the code:

"Cannot run Project.afterEvaluate(Closure) when the project is already evaluated"

Using following versions:
Java 16
Gradle 7.0.2
Gradle Plugin 7.0.0
React Native 0.63.5

package.json :

```
{
  "name": "DTTrainingApp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.15.3",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
    "@react-native-community/picker": "^1.8.0",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^5.9.1",
    "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^5.2.19",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.7.4",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.9.1",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "formik": "^2.2.9",
    "i18next": "^21.6.12",
    "lodash.memoize": "^4.1.2",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-i18next": "^11.15.5",
    "react-native": "0.63.5",
    "react-native-background-timer": "^2.4.1",
    "react-native-calendars": "^1.1280.0",
    "react-native-country-picker-modal": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-create-thumbnail": "^1.6.4",
    "react-native-date-picker": "^3.2.3",
    "react-native-device-info": "^10.0.2",
    "react-native-document-picker": "^5.0.0",
    "react-native-fast-image": "^8.6.3",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.8.0",
    "react-native-image-crop-picker": "^0.35.3",
    "react-native-image-progress": "^1.2.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.4",
    "react-native-lightbox": "^0.8.1",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.5.6",
    "react-native-localize": "^1.4.1",
    "react-native-modal": "^11.5.6",
    "react-native-modalize": "^2.1.1",
    "react-native-onesignal": "^4.5.1",
    "react-native-picker-select": "^8.0.0",
    "react-native-progress": "^4.1.2",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.13.1",
    "react-native-restart": "^0.0.24",
    "react-native-root-toast": "^3.2.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.1.8",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.11.0",
    "react-native-share": "^4.0.1",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.9.1",
    "react-native-sound": "^0.11.2",
    "react-native-swiper": "^1.6.0",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^2.15.2",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^7.1.0",
    "react-native-video": "^5.1.1",
    "react-native-video-player": "^0.10.1",
    "react-native-view-shot": "^3.1.2",
    "react-native-walkthrough-tooltip": "^1.4.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "rn-fetch-blob": "^0.12.0",
    "yup": "^1.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.9.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.9.0",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^1.1.0",
    "babel-jest": "^25.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.5.1",
    "jest": "^25.1.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.59.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.13.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Any help appreciated